# Redirect keyboard input to unfocused program

Tags: linux, io-redirection, keyboard

I'm looking for some help with a computing issue. I'm running Openbox 3.5.2 on Raspbian/Pi3 and a single monitor. I want to have one program focused and in fullscreen while the keyboard outputs to another unfocused and not visible program. The focused program is Epiphany web browser. The un-focused program is an ssh terminal. Thanks for any thoughts/suggestions.

Comment: By definition, the focused window is the one that gets the keyboard input. Do you mean that you want the focus to be on the web browser, but to have only the terminal visible?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Giles, I now realize I miss-understood the terminology of 'focus'. I want to focus the terminal but only have the web browser viable.

A basic method (Openbox 3.5.2, Raspbian, Pi3).
Edit rc.xml to include a window focus key-binding, e.g.  keybind key="W-x"

```
  <action name="PreviousWindow">
    <finalactions>
      <action name="Lower"/>
      <action name="FocusToBottom"/>
      <action name="Focus"/>
    </finalactions>
  </action>
```

The key-binding works with one web browser window & one terminal window.
1: Focus (Alt-Tab) the terminal.
2: Toggle key-binding key (W-x) to focus the terminal window below the browser window.